# RSA-OAEP vs RSA-PKCS1-v1_5

Tags: безопасность, клиент-сервер, криптография, rsa

Как именно RSA-OAEP защищает от "атаки на основе подобранного шифротекста" по сравнению с RSA-PKCS1-v1_5?

Comment: А разве RSA-PKCS1-v1_5 уязвим к этой атаке? Если мне не изменяет память, они оба защищают.

Comment: @Zergatul [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Да, действительно, попутал с подписью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, то при использовании RSA-PKCS1-v1_5 шифруется слишком простое сообщение, а именно:

```
EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M
```

Где PS, случайные ненулевые байты, с минимальной длиной 8 байт. В итоге атакующий может отсылать шифротексты, и с большой вероятностью при расшифровке они сформируют правильную структуру. Нужно только что бы повезло с 3 байтами (0x00, 0x02, 0x00) и что бы все байты в PS были ненулевые (а здесь вероятность очень высока).

RSA-OAEP вначале действует похожим образом, формирует сообщение:

```
DB = lHash || PS || 0x01 || M
```

Но после этого идет дополнительный этап, операция xor с хешами, построенными на основе случайных байт + DB. В итоге получается, что вероятность угадать шифротекст, который расшифруется в правильную структуру, такая же, как угадать результат хеш-функции.

Comment: а что такое "DB"? в принципе все понятно, извините,  а можно ссылку на то где об этом подробнее можно прочитать?

Comment: DB - data block. Это из RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#section-7.1